# Accessing EditText within ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have a ListView with a custom adapter that contains an `EditText`. I want to be able to access this `EditText` and set the text. I am using this code to access the `EditText`'s.

```
    firstName = (EditText)  details.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.editText);
    lastName = (EditText) details.getChildAt(1).findViewById(R.id.editText);
    work = (EditText) details.getChildAt(2).findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mobile = (EditText) details.getChildAt(3).findViewById(R.id.editText);
    home = (EditText) details.getChildAt(4).findViewById(R.id.editText);
    relation = (EditText) details.getChildAt(5).findViewById(R.id.editText);
    primarySwitch = (Switch) details.getChildAt(6).findViewById(R.id.primaryContactSwitch);
```

When I try to access them using a button, it works as expected. When accessing them on the `onCreate` method it crashes with:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Its almost as if I'm accessing the `ListView` before its created. Here is the full code in the `onCreate`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_emergency_contact_details);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    wireUpControls();
    checkForExistingId();
}

private void  wireUpControls(){
    emergencyArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.emergency);
    details = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    EmergencyContactAdapter adapter = new EmergencyContactAdapter(emergencyArray, this);
    details.setAdapter(adapter);

    firstName = (EditText)  details.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.editText);
    lastName = (EditText) details.getChildAt(1).findViewById(R.id.editText);
    work = (EditText) details.getChildAt(2).findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mobile = (EditText) details.getChildAt(3).findViewById(R.id.editText);
    home = (EditText) details.getChildAt(4).findViewById(R.id.editText);
    relation = (EditText) details.getChildAt(5).findViewById(R.id.editText);
    primarySwitch = (Switch) details.getChildAt(6).findViewById(R.id.primaryContactSwitch);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try accessing them on onStart() or onResume() instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` creates the views as you scroll through them. You are trying to access them so early that the views haven't been created yet, so they return null. You should try and find a way to put your `findViewById` logic into your ListView's adapter.

However, I suspect that you shouldn't even be using a `ListView`. If you have static content (in this case, 7 `EditText`), you more likely want a `ScrollView`. The way that you are trying to approach this makes me feel like the `ListView` is not the right tool for the job. (This is also evidenced by the fact that you are passing in a constant array into your ListView's adapter -- ListViews are meant for dynamic data).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the EditText inside getView method in the adapter  like:

```
convertView.findViewById(R.id.your_edittext_id);
```

Now you can set the text on that above editText object only.